# Windows Batch renaming from text document

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I made a Batch script to rename a large amount of files. It takes their name and searches for it in a text document, copies the line and takes the data I need from it and then renames the file.

It seems to work fine for the most part, but I can't check to see how it's doing because it is constantly producing errors/warnings in the console.

```
@echo off
set ogg=.ogg
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.ogg) do (
    set fileNameFull=%%a
    set fileName=!fileNameFull:~0,-4!
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I !fileName! strings.txt') do (
        endlocal
        set "stringLine=%%a%ogg%"
    )
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set fullString=!stringLine:~26!
    ren %%a "!fullString!"
)

pause
```

The code works, I'd just like to be able to track progress, as 10,000s of files are being renamed at a time and I've no indication of how far along the process is.

The errors are:

> ```
> "FINDSTR: Cannot open [...]"
> "The syntax of the command is incorrect."
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.ogg) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%q in ('findstr /I /L /c:"%%~na" strings.txt') do (
     set "stringLine=%%q"
    )
    ECHO ren "%%a" "!stringLine:~26!.ogg"
)

pause
```

This code should be equivalent, but fixed, to the code you've posted.

Fixes:

```
Removed the endlocal/setlocal complication - not required  
changed the inner `for` metavariable - must not be duplicate `%%a`  
Changed the `findstr` switches - add `/L` for literal and `/c:` to force single token in case of a separator-in-name; use `%%~na` to specify "the name part of `%%a`" to avoid the substringing gymnastics.
removed said gymnastics
Removed 2-stage string manipulation of destination filename
Removed superfluous setting of `ogg`
```

The resultant code should duplicate what you have originally, except that it will simply report the `rename` instruction. You should test this against a small representative sample to verify.

for counting/progress:

```
set /a count=0
for %%a in (*.ogg) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%q in ('findstr /I /L /c:"%%~na" strings.txt') do (
     set "stringLine=%%q"
    )
    ECHO ren "%%a" "!stringLine:~26!.ogg"
    set /a count +=1
    set /a stringline= count %% 1000
    if %stringline% equ 0 echo !count! Processed
)

pause
```

which should show you progress each 1000.

You could use

```
    if %stringline% equ 0 echo !count! Processed&pause
```

to wait for user-action before progressing...

BTW -I'm making the assumption that the newname is from column 27+ in your file, since you've not shown us a sample.Also, you should be aware that a simple `findstr` would locate the target string as a substring anywhere within the file - either as the newname or the oldname. If you invoke the `/B` switch on the `findstr`, then the string will match at the very beginning of the line only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, slight problem though.  I had to disable DelayedExpansion because "!" within the strings copied from the text file were being removed.  I think this is causing an issue, but I don't know what the alternative is.

Comment: This is why you should provide sample representative data. It can - and will in this case -  change the entire approach.